# Differents parts on a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I need to add different titles on my combobox but they need to be unclickable. I'll show you with this photo:

[image: item liste]

"Liste 1" and "Liste 2" need to be unclickable.
How can I do this ?

For the moment, this is my code :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxTypeJeu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="297,151,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="146" FontSize="20" SelectedItem="{Binding NumberOfZones, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionChanged="ComboBoxTypeJeu_SelectionChanged" FontFamily="Klavika Bd">
            <sys:Int16>501</sys:Int16>
            <sys:Int16>301</sys:Int16>
            <sys:Int16>11</sys:Int16>
</ComboBox>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide some code. Show us what you did so far.

Comment: do you use WPF? If so, add it to your tags

Comment: I've resolved  what you want :)

Comment: @ValentinGuibert please see whether [this](https://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/silverlight-combobox-with-treeview-inside/) might be of use to you. If not, you would have to redesign the `ComboBox`'s template whilst preserving the data binding functionality, which will likely be some hard work.

Comment: try `Focusable="false"`

Comment: To make my point more clear: you should not work with manually added `TextBlock`s with `Focusable="False"`, `Enabled="False"` etc. etc. because using that will not work with data binding, which is a great feature that you might miss later.

Comment: I've try with your comments and it doesn"t work. I think I need to use your first link @ThomasFlinkow, but it's a little difficult... :)